# C#-Getting to grips with Client-Server

Tags: c#, client-server

I am wondering about a client-server requests and response set up.

I am trying to understand how to set this up. My scenario is this:

I have an application thats partly a client. In other words, it doesn't need the server application to perform its core functionality but it does need to be able to send instructions to a server application, which then has to perform a set of operations based on the instruction.

Now my main question is how do I send the instructions?

Is it in the form of a string that gets parsed server side and performs its instruction based on the parsed results or is there another way to send instructions to a server?

Just trying to get some understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of .NET 3.5. there's a set of technologies called [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) which handles all of the details of remote calls for you; as a core part of the framework, it's also well supported in Visual Studio, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Read about ASP.Net WebService.

You can create a class-like interface that can be referenced from the client and communicated like a regular object.

[Simplest webservice example with visual studio](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359)
[All About Web Service in .Net (good walk-through)](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2007/09/all-about-web-service-in-net.html)